# Showing that an evaluation map is continuous

Tags: general-topology

This is a problem from Munkres' Topology 43.8

If $X$ and $Y$ are spaces, define

*e* : $X \times \mathscr {C}(X,Y) \to Y$

by the equation *e*($x,f$) $= f(x)$; the map *e* is called the **evaluation map**. Show that if $d$ is a metric for $Y$ and $\mathscr {C}(X,Y)$ has the corresponding uniform topology, then *e* is continuous.

I'm not sure how I can use the properties of a uniform topology to show that this map is continuous. Any solution, hints, or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Check continuity at a point $(x_0, f_0)$. You want (for an arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$) neighbourhoods $U(x_0)$ and $V(f_0)$ such that $d(f(x),f_0(x_0)) < \varepsilon$ for all $(x,f)\in U(x_0)\times V(f_0)$.